# Postgresql 12.2 COPY сохраняет файлы с русским названием с слетевшей кодировкой

Tags: postgresql, кодировка

Имеем:

- Postgresql 12.2 64 на Windows 10 (сервер и клиент на одном ПК);
- PGadmin ;
- Задачу по выгрузке файла с БД на локальный ПК с русским названием
  (именно с русским);

Что делаю:

```
copy (select  'Корона' as Вирус  , 'Нет' as Лекарство ) to 'C:/temp/Название.csv'   DELIMITER ' '  CSV ENCODING 'WIN1251'HEADER ;
```

Что получаю:

- Название файла - РќР°Р·РІР°РЅРёРµ.csv
- В самом фале всё по русски, как и предполагалось

В дальнейшем этот код обрастет функцией, которая будет нарезать файлы, согласно списка и называть их согласно определенным условиям. Но главное условие - название на русском.

Куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Пересоздал БД, всё получилось

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name1
    WITH 
    OWNER = postgres
    ENCODING = 'WIN1251'
    LC_COLLATE = 'ru-RU'
    LC_CTYPE = 'ru-RU'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

или так

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name1 WITH template=template0 encoding=WIN1251
```